# What is the need to copy, or slice, an array vs. creating a variable that is just equal to existing one?

Tags: javascript

```
let a = {"foo": 99};
let b = a;
// console.log(b)  {"foo": 99}

a.foo = 33;
// console.log(b)  {"foo": 33}
```

I understand in the scenario above that if I use objects, the variable referencing the original object will reflect the value of the original object.

But if I do this with arrays:

```
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = a;

a = [99,99,99];
// console.log(b) [1,2,3];
```

variable `b` still references the original value of `a` even after `a` changed so then what would the person of creating a copy via `slice()` serve?

Comment: both arrays and object are passed by reference, so why this is util, is when you want to create an array with the same properties but maybe add something new, or change a given index value

```javascript
const a = [1]
const b = [...a] // this is shallow only
b.push(2)
// a = [1], b = [1,2]
```

Comment: Try the following: `let a = [1, 2, 3]; let b = a; a.sort((x, y) => y - x)` and check `b`. Alternative: `let a = [1, 2, 3]; let b = a; a.splice(1, 1)` and check `b` again. Now imagine that you're mutating an array that is passed into a function - what would `a` be after this call? `a = [1, 2, 3]; fn(a);`. The answer is simple - since the array is mutated, then *nobody knows*. Not until you check what the function does and even then it would take some time. If `fn` did a copy first, then you don't have such problem.

Comment: Also worth noting: "*But if I do this with arrays*" you're *not* doing the same thing with arrays. You'd get the same behaviour with objects as you had with arrays if you used equivalent code for `let a = {"foo": 99}; let b = a; a = {"foo": 33}`. And you'd get the same behaviour with arrays as with objects had you used equivalent code: `let a = [1,2,3]; let b = a; a[1] = 99;`. So the two pieces of functionality you show are simply completely different and not at all connected specifically with just objects or just arrays. Arrays *are* objects, after all.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, by doing `a = [99, 99, 99]`, you are creating an entirely new object, and "resetting" `a`. But when doing `a.foo = 33`, you are modifying an existing object and references to it.

You can see that when I set `a[0]` instead of `a`, `b` still equals `a`:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a;

a[0] = [99, 99, 99];
console.log(b);
```

When using the `slice()` method, `b` retains `a`'s original value.

Example:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a;

a = a.slice(2);
console.log(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a loosely typed language, which means that you don’t have to specify what type of data will be stored in a variable in advance.

In your case, you have selected
let a=[1,2,3]; which gets overridden later.
but let suppose you had something like the below.

```
let a = [{name: 'David'}, {name: 'Tim'}];
let b = a;
b[0].name = 'Bruce';
console.log(a[0].name); //Bruce
```

In the aforementioned example, you see that the array assignment to a different variable won't help you retain the actual value in your original array. Hence, it's always better to copy the array instead of just assigning it to another variable if it needs modification.

In addition, when copying it is always better to do a deep copy to avoid missing information.