# change in original array if I change the copied one

Tags: javascript, arrays

Again a confusing Issue:

Here I copied the array into another variable and I expect not to change the original array when I change something in another one but both arrays change Why?

```js
 const groups = [[1, 2, 3, 4 ,5], [2,3]];
 const sets = [...groups];
 
 sets[1].push(9000); // I just push a number into sets NOT groups
 
 console.log(sets);
 console.log(groups);
```

This only happens if we have an array of arrays!

What I'm missing and How to fix this?

Comment: The spread syntax performs a shallow copy, not a _deep_ copy. The arrays inside of the copied array are still references to the same arrays that are in the `groups` arrays.

Comment: wait....what? so what should I do...

Comment: if its just a 2d array, you could do something like `const sets = groups.map(arr => [...arr])`, this will clone each inner array, and will be stored in the resulting outer array produced by .map().

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator does only shallow copy of groups. So the arrays are copied by reference and if you change those, the original arrays are affected.

Edit: if you need a deep clone, you may want to look here:
[Deep copy in ES6 using the spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-syntax) (JSON.stringify/JSON.parse should prevent another 3rd party library).

Comment: Interesting - that's nearly the same answer than Nick Parsons comment...

Comment: What should I do not to affect the original array?

Comment: Deep clone, I've attached a link to a duplicate that should point you to the right answer

Comment: Coincidentally, there's actually a somewhat closely related answer posted by me just yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158339/12984567